# How to populate one combobox with an SQL dataTable and with an item seperate from that table

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

Sorry if the title is a bit vague - it is difficult to capture what i want to do in one sentence, so I'll quickly explain what I want to achieve.

I want to bind an SQL table to a comboBox and have all its values (Item names for example) but I also wish to add one of my own items into the same comboBox, separate from the table (For example - "Add new" should then be inserted at the bottom of the list after the SQL table values have been loaded in the comboBox).

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you mean combobox.Items.Add(your item)?

Comment: Well, yes. Initially - after a dataSet (For example: Clients) have been inserted into the combobox.

Comment: yup, do the same after your dataset binding

Answer (score 3):

You can assign datasource in code-behind like this.

```
cmb1.DataSource=dt;
cmb1.DataBind();
cmb1.Items.Insert(dt.Rows.Count,new ComboBoxItem("Add New","0"));
cmb1.appenddatabounditems="true";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Insert**, you have to specify **index** and new **item** to add in list.

```
cmb1.Items.Insert(tabl.rows.count,"Add new");
```

**OR**

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Text = "Add new";
item.Value = 0;

cmb1.Items.Add(item);
```

If you not specify any index it will append at last

Comment: Okay, I understand. Is there a way to add it to the bottom of the list, meaning to add it in the last index's position?

Comment: i have give you code for last index. tabl.rows.count-1=total items in combobox